# Accessing models by using a variable

Tags: prisma

How can I **dynamically** access a **model** in prisma?

```
return await prisma[modelName].create({ data })
```

*... seems not to work.*

I am looking for a way to access my models by using a variable. How can this be done?

---

**Update:**

There is a typescript error: `Unable to compile TypeScript`.

```
error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'PrismaClient<PrismaClientOptions, never, RejectOnNotFound | RejectPerOperation | undefined>'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'PrismaClient<PrismaClientOptions, never, RejectOnNotFound | RejectPerOperation | undefined>'.
```

Comment: "Not to work" in what way? Is there some error? Could you clarify what happens?

Comment: This doesn't fully answer your question, but you can get rid of the `string` type by replacing it with `type ModelName = Uncapitalize<Prisma.ModelName>` (importing `import { Prisma } from "@prisma/client"`). You will still get an error if you try creating a new object with `prisma[myModelName].create`: `Each member of the union type ... has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other."`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a bit hacky but you can use `// @ts-ignore` above the line to avoid the error you mentioned.

This should work fine:

```js
// @ts-ignore
return await prisma[modelName].create({ data });
```

I fully understand there should be a better way to do this. However this is by far the simplest way without resorting to private APIs.

Comment: This might be a bit old, but this one worked for me.